# What event is triggered when user selects value from drop down ComboBox (ActiveX)?

Tags: vba, excel, activexobject

What event is triggered when user selects value from drop down ComboBox (Active X). How it can be defined in VBA. I would like to trigger macro when value is selected from drop down.

Comment: `ComboBox_Change` event is triggered when a user selects a value. `ActiveX` have their own events you can use to run routines. I see you have previous questions related to this as well. Might as well add illustration or screen shot of your issue or what you're trying to achieve. That will add clarity and will attract more answers.

Comment: Combobox_change event triggered as soon as i started to type. (Auto search drop down). So cannot use this property to trigger event. I am using ActiveX combo box

Comment: It has to be like when user selects value from drop down then move focus to next drop down else show msg:"Select value from drop down"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ComboBox_Click()` is the event you are looking for.

Comment: This event triggers as soon as you click on the object. I think not applicable to what the OP wants.

Comment: From my testing, it works only after selecting item from dropdown (working in Excel 2010).

Comment: Ok my bad. You are correct. But again, it will not work if OP decides to type the value in the Combo box to use the auto complete feature of the control.

Comment: I agree. In that case some combination of events + conditions will be needed, but we are beyond the question scope.

Comment: I think the problem is when ever the excel sheet is updated to any value then last used drop down automatically pops up!

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain that in other words? Maybe update the original question with current state.

Comment: Is there a wayto disable dropdown(Only Drop down not combobox) and enable dropdown on event. Like Disable when lost focus enable when got focus

Comment: @Branislav Kollár Is there a way i can send the file itself?

Comment: There is a property of combobox exactly for what you are asking about. You lucky ... :D `ComboBox.ShowDropButtonWhen = fmShowDropButtonWhenFocus`

Comment: I'm a bit confused now, we have a communication delay. Is it working as intedned now, or do we have some work to do?

Comment: Still problem persists. "ComboBox.ShowDropButtonWhen = fmShowDropButtonWhenFocus" is just making the dropdown symbol to go away. Its not making dropdown go away.

Comment: We are talking about the Countrydd and Divisiondd comboboxes, right? I can see, that their dropdown lists persist, even when changing sheets. Is this the issue you are trying to amend?

Comment: Yes. Drop down persist when ever we change any value in the cell. But can able to change value in cell when we open the excel and try to edit cell(With out using dropdown). I am missing something when we first use the drop down.

Comment: I think we need a **new question**, with **specific definition of problem, misbehaviour and desired behaviour**. I don't think I understand what is going on in there. Someone else maybe can help. I will give it a shot, though.

Comment: Thanks Branislav Kollár

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `ComboBox` control in a `UserForm`, it usually have an `AfterUpdate Event`. 
If you're using an `ActiveX Control ComboBox` in a Sheet, you can try `LostFocus Event`.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_LostFocus()

End Sub
```

This way, you can type in values and then run the routine after you select another object.

Comment: I tried that. Here is the scenario. I have two drop down activex combo box
the first drop down parameters are                                                 Change (1)
gotFocus
Dropdown button click
LostFocus             
the second drop down parameters are                                                Change (1)
gotFocus
Dropdown button click
LostFocus                                                                                                            Assigned these values to the specified event trigger. After using both the combo box. Still change event is trigerring(Even lost focus)