# combo box (form control) paste selected string name to cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to paste the value of the selected content in a combobox (form control) to a cell (B12) without having to add a button triggering this event.

Here's my code;

```
Sub drop_down_16_change()
With Worksheets("Dashboard").Shapes("Drop Down 16").ControlFormat
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A12") = .List(.Value)
End With
End Sub
```

However, it does not work when changing selected item in the dropdownbox, only works when running the script.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362456/what-event-is-triggered-when-user-selects-value-from-drop-down-combobox-activex

Comment: You are simply using form controls instead of ActiveX controls? In that case you can link a cell to the chosen index of the combobox. In cell `A12` you can then just put an index formula to get the corresponding value from the listrange.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. You need to right click on the combobox and then click on assign macro and then select `drop_down_16_change` ;) it will now work

Comment: Thanks , problem solved!